# Как парсить HTML который создается через JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, парсер

как парсить HTML который создается через JS JavaScript то есть динамическую страницу, JSOUP с этим не справился это то и ясно, хотел попробовать через OkHttp но не смог войти в консоль из-за проблем с куками. Как поступать, через okHttp ? если да, не могли подсказать как там сохранять и использовать куки, т.к на просторах интернета не нашел.

Comment: OkHttp тоже не справится. Для этого нужны средства типа Selenium.

Comment: не могли бы по подробнее ?

Comment: Чтобы получать данные генерируемые javascript'ом, надо уметь этот javascript выполнять. Библиотеки типа JSoup и OkHttp просто отправлять http-запрос web-серверу, получают http-ответ и возвращают вызывающему коду текст ответа или его часть, отфильтрованную по какому-либо признаку. Никакой обработки текста ответа они не делают. А [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) прикидывается полноценным бразуером, строя DOM из полученного html-кода и запуская на нём javascript.

Comment: Для таких целей используйте Selenium.

Comment: не могли бы показать немного кода, как получить html?